# Have governments ever made female genital mutilation compulsory?

Tags: civil-rights, feminism, islamic-state

ISIS has recently been accused of making female genital mutilation (FGM) compulsory for girls and women under the age of 49. They've [denied the claim](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jul/24/isis-deny-ordering-fgm-girls-mosul).

My understanding was that no government has ever made FGM compulsory, and that in some countries where FGM happens there are (poorly enforced) laws against it.

Has any government, ever, made FGM compulsory for a large range of women? By "a large range", I mean that a government mistreating mental patients, or doing Mengele-style "experiments" in concentration camps wouldn't count.

Comment: As the ISIS claim has not only been denied by ISIS to be wrong, but also independently revealed to be a hoax, I suggest changing this question to be more generic. Something about crying wolf, and it ending up being bad for everyone. See http://blog.foreignpolicy.com/posts/2014/07/24/islamic_state_isn_t_circumcising_women_and_didn_t_steal_400_million_either.

Comment: "ever" is a bit broad here. I'm sure there were Sharia-like tribal "governments" (for a broad def of the latter term) that probably deferred on such matters to religious authorities. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia#Pre-modern_Islamic_legal_system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, based on Wikipedia's page on [prevalence of female genital mutilation by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalence_of_female_genital_mutilation_by_country) no government mandates it (currently). There are, however, countries with a very high rate of female genital mutilation / cutting (FGM/C), see the image below based on data by UNICEF:
[image]
<sub>[Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalence_of_female_genital_mutilation_by_country#/media/File:Composite_FGM_world_map.svg) by [Nederlandse Leeuw](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Nederlandse_Leeuw) / [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0)</sub>

For many of the countries on that page , it mentions religion as the main motivator (use CTRL+f and *'religion'* on that page). For example:

> A majority of Gambian women who underwent FGM/C claimed they did it primarily because religion mandates it.